# Regex to select the words those match brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the full forms using regex using javascript

I have tried with

```
(\w+\s*[^a-z^A-Z]*){3}\s*\([A-Z]*\)
```

but the extraction fails when there are some full forms like these

Most **common mis'take** (MCM)
(only bold is selected)

**Below is the text for testing:**

The task of automatically extracting acronymdefinition pairs from biomedical literature has

Most common mis'take (MCM)
been studied, almost exclusively for English, over
the past few decades using technologies from Natural Language Processing (NLP). This section
167
presents a few approaches and techniques that
were applied to the acronym identification task.
Taghva and Gilbreth (1999) present the Acronyms 7'-  $ **** Finding Program (AFP)

, based on
pattern matching. Their program seeks for
acronym candidates which appear as upper case
words. They calculate a heuristic score for each
competing definition by classifying words into:
(1) stop words (”the”, ”of”, ”and”), (2) hyphenated words (3) normal words (words that don’t
fall into any of the above categories) and (4) the
acronyms themselves (since an acronym can
sometimes be a part of the definition). The AFP
utilizes the Longest Common Subsequence (LCS)
algorithm (Hunt and Szymanski, 1977) to find all
possible alignments of the acronym to the text,
followed by simple scoring rules which are based
on matches. The performance reported from their
experiment are: recall of 86% at precision of 98%

Comment: I suppose this has to be "dynamic"? Would there be abbreviations of just two (even a single) letter(s)? Or more than three for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repeating the group 3 times, you could use 3 capturing groups with a backreference to those groups matching the first letter of the word.

```
\b(\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* (\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* (\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* \(\1\2\3\)
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(\w)` Match a single word char in **group 1**
- `[\w']*` Match 0+ times a word char or `'`
- `[^a-zA-Z()]*`  Match 0+ times any char except the listed, then match a space
- `(\w)[\w'][^a-zA-Z()]`  Same as above with **group 2**
- `(\w)[\w'][^a-zA-Z()]`  Same as above with **group 3**
- `(\1\2\3)` Between parenthesis, use the 3 backreferences to the capturing groups

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVtPMz/1)

---

You could also update your pattern by adding the `'` to the character class and repeat that 0+ times `[\w']*`

You can extend the character class with characters you would allow to match.

```
\b(?:\w[\w']* [^a-zA-Z]*){3} ?\([A-Z]{3}\)
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w[\w']*`  Match a word char and 0+ times any char except a word char or ', then match a space
  - `[^a-zA-Z]*` Match 0+ times any char except a-zA-Z
- `){3} ?` Repeat 3 times and match optional space
- `\([A-Z]{3}\)` Match 3 occurrences of A-Z between parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN6ok3/1)

Comment: I think your first patterns is stronger since the second one would match `natural Language Processing (NP)`

Comment: @JvdV You are right, the second one is an adjustment of the OP's pattern to get the full matches.

Comment: @JvdV; I guess giving a generic one is not possible here; since the Full forms, addresses, etc. consists of infinte language and also are not [**regular.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)

Comment: It's why I won't try to build a pattern myself, though if they only ever are 3-digit then the attempt above by @Thefourthbird is as good as it gets upto a certain extend.

Comment: Agreed; But this language is infinite if you see the generic context and there is no pattern on which to pump the FA; and hence it will not be accepted only by regular expression. Although; by code logic along with regex it can be possible since all the HLL fall under Context Sensitive lang.

Comment: \b(\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* (\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* (\w)[\w']*[^a-zA-Z()]* \(\1\2\3\)
How can I adapt for second, third and four character abbreviations to n number?

Comment: @CodeGuy One way is to make the third and the fourth part optional https://regex101.com/r/ZnhpFL/1